# Close camera preview after certain time

Tags: python, opencv, timer

I want to close the OpenCV camera preview after a certain time.How can I do that I have tried with following code but it isn't showing camera preview because of the timer.

```
import time
timeout = time.time() + 60*5


if time.time() > timeout:
   break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the frames by using `while loop` and specify the `condition` as follows:

```
import cv2
import time

timeout = time.time() + 10  # 10 s
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while time.time() < timeout: # set the time out rule
  _, frame = cap.read()
  cv2.waitKey(1)
  cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
  
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import  time
timeout  =  time.time( )  + 60*5


if time.time() > timeout:
   break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.